# Need to find who owns our Google API key

Tags: google-api, recover

Recently I started working in a small startup company and we need to add Google+ Api support to the other Google Api we are using. (That is google reader api). However the person who registered our application is long gone, and to discover who it was I need to find out with what email it was registered. How can i recover the email address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try contacting google .... there are email addresses and support phone numbers here ->

http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/static.py?page=contacting_support.html